# Storing query as a int to check to see if more than one exists

Tags: sql, count, duplicates

The code is suppose to check my database to see if there are duplicates of activityName existing if that query runs I am suppose to get an error stating that the activity name is taken else if there isn't any activity name in that database with the same name then the activity name would be inserted into the database. Im suppose to execute the query and get the result as an Integer then use the result in the if and else to see if result>0 in the database

```
var queryCount= 'SELECT COUNT (activityName) FROM dataEntryTb WHERE activityName = "'+an+'" ';
            tx.executeSql(queryCount,[]);
            if(queryCount > 0){
            navigator.notification.alert("Activity Name Taken");
            }else{
```

Comment: Define "isn't working".

Comment: The code is suppose to check my database to see if there are duplicates of activityName existing if that query runs I am suppose to get an error stating that the activity name is taken else if there isn't any activity name in that database with the same name then the activity name would be inserted into the database

Comment: Im suppose to execute the query and get the result as an Integer then use the result in the if and else to see if result>0 in the database

Comment: You should check the result of the query, not the query itself...

Comment: Can you tell me how to store the result of the queryCount query as an integer>

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what's the issue exactly but it should work fine. You can consider changing it like

```
var queryCount= "SELECT 1 FROM dataEntryTb WHERE activityName = '" + an + "'";
```

Again, consider using parameterized query instead of string concatenation to avoid *SQL Injection* (if `an` is coming as user input)

Comment: The main problem is executing the queryCount query and getting the results as an integer I am not sure how to correctly store a query as an integer

Comment: Ok I understand where you are coming from Mr Rahul but I am trying to figure out still how to store the query as an Int after I execute it.